# Flex Box: automatic break to new line

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have an DIV container that has N children (usually 2 or 3).
Those children are all canvas nodes with different heights (some from chart.js, some from other libs).

I needed to align those items vertically so i used this css in the parent element:

```
.wrapper{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

When the window is resized to a smaller width, elements on the row will disappear outside the screen. By design we must negate any horizontal scroll on the screen. All content must reside inside the screen's width.

I am trying to obtain the "auto-break-to-new-line" effect that usually we can get with:

```
.wrapper{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

How can i have a flex box to automatically break to new line, when the window is resized to a smaller width?

I can also accept answers that enable perfect vertical alignment for nodes in a parent div with display: inline-block set.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#flex-wrap

Answer (score 7):

By default flexbox container is set to not wrap. You can change it via flex-wrap property.

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap